How to install dual boot 24.04 on zfs root?
In have win 11 installed on nvme partition and tried to install to install zfs on an other partition. But the wizard for zfs wipe allthe disk.I tried with a custom procedure but there isn't opztion to format zfs on a disk partition.
Any trick to do it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Even the official ZFS documentation (for Ubuntu 22.04) states that you must clear the partition table for their guide to work.
It might be possible to tweak the guide, and install the required ZFS pools on different partitions instead, but this offsets some of the advantages of ZFS as a disk manager.
I'm not aware of any other method that can provide ZFS boot in a dual-boot environment.

This is definitely possible. I have several Windows/Linux dual boot systems where the Linux part is using (encrypted) ZFS. I set these up by varying the Ubuntu Root on ZFS documentation you linked, but allocating new partitions and not zapping the entire table, and also by sharing the ESP (EFI) with Windows. It all works, but you need to understand clearly how Linux booting works. I practiced in a VM first.
